# Display loading image till timepicker not update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using timepicker with dependent multiple timepickers. And write jquery to update all other timepicker time when i change single timepicker from view. My jquery as below :

```
 $("#empattendance-ea_check_in").timepicker("option", "onClose", function(time) {
    $(".check-in-time").timepicker("setTime", time);
});
```

`#empattendance-ea_check_in` is my single timepicker when i change this picker all timepicker having class `.check-in-time` will be update.

Everything work smoothly. My issue is, i want to display loading image till all other timepicker will not update. Right now onClose timepicker event loading image will display but i did not find any success event to close that loading image. Is there any event or method to hide loading image?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: sorry it's not exactly clear what you're asking. At what point in the processing do you want the loading image to be shown, and when do you want it to hide again?

Comment: @ADyson : When i am going to more then 100 record using `Jquery` it will stuck my screen so end user will confused what to do? Actually in back ground (In Jquery client script) is running to update other timepicker values. So my requirement is to display loading image dialog till this Jquery request is running and after complete hide loading image.

Answer (score 0):

This code is just running synchronously so as far as I can see there's no need to handle any events, or look for callback functions.

If you have a loading image (or a div with an image and a modal background might make sense) you can just simply show it before you run the update command, and hide it afterwards:

```
$("#empattendance-ea_check_in").timepicker("option", "onClose", function(time) {
  $("#LoadingImage").show();
  $(".check-in-time").timepicker("setTime", time);
  $("#LoadingImage").hide();
});
```

Even if you have 100 timepickers, as you mention in the comments, I'd be a bit surprised if this took more than a second or two to complete in a modern browser, but this will deal with that if it becomes a problem.

As an aside, if you have a page with 100 separate editable rows on it, maybe it's time for a UI redesign :-)

Comment: I will check it out and then get back to you.

Comment: Its not working. Line which hide loading image after updating all time picker do not show loading image. I think all the task are running parallel. When i comment  `$("#LoadingImage").hide();` line it shows loading image. That loading image show only when all time picker will update.

Comment: ok. what's the timepicker component you are using? does it have any documentation online? that way we can find out if things are running in parallel, or whether there is any event that can be handled when it finishes

Comment: Its just a textbox but after that i am apply jquery to convert that into timepicker. Use just timepicker jquery.

Comment: which one? there are lots of different possibilities: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=timepicker+jquery&oq=timepicker+jquery&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.247j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8